# C#- Passing array to Html.PagedListPager

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Html.PagedListPager extension for paging in my application. I want to pass array of integer to this method. Following is my code

```
@Html.PagedListPager(
   Model.NewListProjectModel, page => Url.Action(
       "PartialProjectListing",
       new { page, Model.SearchModel.Sectors }
    ), PagedList.Mvc.PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(
        new AjaxOptions() {
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            UpdateTargetId = "PartialListingProjects",
            OnSuccess = "$.moveToTop('#PartialListingProjects>div')" 
        }
    )
)
```